# How to check if my property exists in type

Tags: typescript

As far as we know typescript allow us to declare partially types but what when we gonna to check if my property is in keyof Type.
Let's see

```
interface Car {
   Brand: string;
   Model: string;
}

type KeyofCar = keyof Car; // Brand, Model

if('Brand' is in KeyofCar) {
   something...
} // I know it doesn't work but it is pseudocode
```

Is there any way to find out that?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with an interface at the moment, see [this feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17061).

Comment: I know the interfaces are abstract types so it's hard to reach what i'm looking for, but maybe someone discovered solution.

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing, there isn't a way to check for this at runtime strictly using Typescript mechanisms. Though a kinda ugly hack you can do is create a Record then extract the keys from it.

```
interface Car {
   Brand: string;
   Model: string;
}

const carRecord: Record<keyof Car, boolean> = {
  Brand: true,
  Model: true
}

if (carRecord['Brand']) {
  something...
}
```

The reason you do a `Record` is because every time you change the interface, you must also change the `Record`.  Otherwise, Typescript will throw compile errors. At the very least this ensures that the check will remain consistent as the `Car` interface grows.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're going for here. In your question you know at compile time that `'Brand'` *is* in `keyof Car`. So why would you check for it?

I could imagine trying to do something like that if the type is not completely known, like in a type argument...

```
function<T>(foo: T) {
  // this is not possible because keyof does not exist in runtime contexts
  if('bar' in keyof T) {
    // do something...
  }
}
```

I would say you wouldn't try to solve the problem by comparing something to `keyof T`. Instead try to do something like this

```
interface Car {
  Brand: string;
  Model: string;
}

interface Bus {
  Passengers: number;
  Color: string;
}

function(foo: Car | Bus) {
  if('Brand' in foo) {
    // foo is a Car
  } else {
    // foo is a Bus
  }
}
```

If you really want to do something with the keys you could do something like this

```
type CarKey = keyof Car;
const carKeys: CarKey[] = ['Brand', 'Model'];

function(key: string) {
  if(carKeys.includes(key)) {
    // do thing
  }
}
```

Or to be even more sure that you have *every* key

```
type CarKey = keyof Car;
const carKeys = Object.keys({
    Brand: null, 
    Model: null
} satisfies Record<CarKey, null>) as Array<keyof Car>;

function isKeyOfCar(key: string): key is CarKey {
    return carKeys.includes(key);
}
```

That way if the `Car` type changes over time, you'll know if these keys need to be updated.

Comment: `keyof T` won't work outside of `type` or `interface` context - how will you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
type CheckPropExists<T extends {[x:string]:any},Prop extends string> = T[Prop] extends undefined ? false : true;
//Example
type Result = CheckPropExists<{a:string;b:number;},"a">;
//Result is true
```

Comment: Works well, except it works with string types, not string vars...

Comment: This always returns `true` because a non existent key resolves to `any`, not undefined.
Check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgCygYwNYAUBOB7CBRADwEsBnEEgHgBUYoCQoA7AExJgG8BtAgLjMyKMA5gF0eAQ0ZgAvgBosuWvSasY-QUIB8MALwwqnBRBFKGLNgFcWUAGaCozGAH4YN8QBsSsHjBCYLUADcwAD0IYTiALYQ7lCgkLAASlAkFu4guvBIaEaEpOQU7OJ8fhqBAEY8jBaR5VCYgXIAROJNmsHx0DDJqekATJmIKBg4+MRklEUlAsIVVTV1Dc1wbcEwMEA)